# CakePHP - unwanted HABTM contained in find using "contain"

Tags: cakephp

I'm creating a messaging system using CakePHP. In terms of models,

```
Users HABTM Conversations
Conversations hasMany Messages
Messages belongTo User (the sender)
```

So I'm running a find condition on Users, and the contain is as follows:

```
$user = $this->Conversation->User->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('User.id' => $user_id),
        'contain' => array(
            'Conversation' => array(
                'ConversationsUser',
                'Message' => array(
                    'order' => 'Message.created DESC',
                    'limit' => 1,
                    'User' => array(
                        'Student' => array(
                            'University'
                        ),
                        'Recruiter' => array(
                            'Org'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ));
```

When I get the results, I get $user['Conversation']['Message']['User']['Conversation'] - basically, the HABTM join is automatically done 3 levels deep and there's no way for me to prevent it. Is there any way for me to remove this information from the find?

Comment: Where did you set the containable behavior? If you don't set in in the AppModel (or seperately in _each_ model), I could imagine that if you contain a model that doesn't use the Containable behavior, that model would then fetch related data according to its 'recursive' setting.  (This is something of a guess, which is why I didn't write it as an answer yet)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I restructured the find by doing:

```
$this->Conversation->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('ConversationsUser')));
$conversations = $this->Conversation->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('ConversationsUser.user_id' => $user_id),
        'order' => 'Conversation.modified DESC',
        'contain' => array(
            'ConversationsUser',
            'User' => array(
                'conditions' => array('User.id <> ' . $user_id),
                'ProfilePhoto' => array(
                    'Attachment'
                ),
                'Student' => array(
                    'University'
                ),
                'Recruiter' => array(
                    'Org'
                )
            ),
            'Message' => array(
                'order' => 'Message.created DESC'
            )
        )
    ));
```

I didn't really need to have the User within the Message.